# How to escape { character in FromSqlRaw query

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

In EF Core using Npsql EF Core data provider , queries like

```
await ctx.Doc.FromSqlRaw(@"select * from Doc where id=any('{1,2,3}')");
```

throw an error

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

How to use `{` and `}` characters in queries so that those are not treated as parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with string.Format, use double curlies to escape:

```cs
await ctx.Doc.FromSqlRaw(@"select * from Doc where id=any('{{1,2,3}}')");
```